# Formato Fecha de Excel en Java

Tags: java, excel, date

Tengo una consulta, espero alguien me pueda ayudar:

En excel, dentro de una celda tengo una fecha por ejemplo la de hoy:

```
2/12/2018
```

A esta celda le doy click derecho -> Formato de celdas y la formateo como número, con lo cual tengo el siguiente resultado:

```
43439,67
```

¿Cómo hago en Java para obtener este número? He intentado con el siguiente código:

```
Date fecha = new Date();
System.out.println(fecha.getTime());
```

Y obtengo como resultado:

```
1544043888569
```

Comment: Revisate este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19028192)

Comment: Gracias Orlando, ya lo había revisado, lo que hacen ahí es: ya una vez obtenido el número "43439,67", lo pasan a formato fecha, lo que yo necesito es el número "43439,67" que corresponde a la fecha de hoy, gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Por eso coloque el enlace, ya que hacen referencia a la documentacion de la libreria [POI](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html), donde contiene algunos metodos (`getExcelDate`) que le pasan una fecha y retornan un numero e incluso tiene unos metodos para validar los valores. ¿Ya probaste algunos de esos metodos?

Comment: @DavidDavila no agregues solucionado a tu título, asi no funciona esta plataforma

Comment: si tu mismo respondiste a tu pregunta entonces solo acepta tu respuesta y con eso se entiende que ya esta contestada

Comment: No lo sabía, gracias por la corrección @shadow Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado con el siguiente código:

```
Date fecha = new Date();
double dias = fecha.getTime() / 1000.0 / 86400 + 70 * 365.25 + 1;
System.out.println(dias);
```

La función "getTime()" retorna el número de milisegundos desde el 1/1/1970 hasta la presente fecha; por otro lado Excel retorna el número de días desde 31/12/1899 hasta la presente fecha; por lo tanto lo que se hace es una conversión.